# R list package ict.reg will not run

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and trying to diagnose a problem when running "ict.reg" in the list package (developed for list experiements). When I try to run ict.reg, it returns this error message:

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Location 2 doesn't exist.
i There are only 1 column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In if (class(t) == "factor") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I've tried a few things like making sure the "treat" variable is boolean, but it still comes up with this message that I am struggling to figure out. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
install.packages(list)

# Load package
library(list)

experimentA$treat <- ifelse(is.na (experimentA$treatmentA),FALSE, TRUE))

# Test No Design Effect Assumption:
# experiementA = dataset
# listA= list items reported by respondent
# binary = binary variable denoting whether individual received treatment or control list
# J = number of control list items

# Generate estimate of population proportion based on difference in means
diff.in.means.results<-ictreg(listA~1, data=experimentA, treat="treat", J=3,method='lm')
summary(diff.in.means.results)
```

Comment: Could you please reduce the amount of code to the minimum that is enough to show or reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just tried to edit for clarity, hope this was helpful! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Answer provided in case anyone runs into this error message.* I encountered this error when using a tibble, i.e., data imported from an SPSS file using `haven::read_sav('FILE.sav')`. Once this object was converted to a standard data frame using `df2 <- as.data.frame(df)`, then the `ictreg()` function from the `list` package worked as expected.